# Proofs with enumerations of all rationals

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

I am trying to review for a test and I came across a problem that I do not know how to do.

Let (Qn) be an enumeration of all the rationals in the interval (0,infinity)

A. Prove that Inf(Qn) with n>k = 0 for every k>= 1

B. Use part a to find liminf as n goes to infinity of Qn

C. Prove (Qn) has a monotone subsequence (Qnk) such that the limit as k approaches infinity of (Qnk) = 0

Answer (score 0):

C) We define the subsequence recursively. Let $n_1$ be the smallest index $i$ such that $Q_i\lt 1$.

Suppose that we have found indices $n_1,n_2,\dots n_k$ such that the finite subsequence  $Q_{n_1}, Q_{n_2}, \dots, Q_{n_k}$ is decreasing  and $Q_{n_i}\lt \frac{1}{i}$  for all $i\le k$. We show how to find $Q_{n_{k+1}}$ such that the subsequence continues to decrease and $Q_{n_{k+1}}\lt \frac{1}{k+1}$.

There are only finitely many rationals in the collection of all $Q_i$  with $i\le n_k$, and there are infinitely many rationals $r$ such that $0\lt r\lt \frac{1}{k+1}$ and $0\lt r\lt Q_{n_j}$ for all $n_j\le n_k$.

Let $n_{k+1}$ be the smallest index $\gt n_k$  such that $0\lt Q_{n_{k+1}}\lt \frac{1}{k+1}$ and $0\lt Q_{n_{k+1}}\lt Q_{n_j}$ for all $n_j\le n_k$.